# Minecraft [any version] - Flashing/Graphical Glitches?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, graphics-card

I recently reset my PC, and have noticed that since I have done so, Minecraft has been acting strangely. Whenever I play, the entire game window [GUI and all] flashes white for an instant. Or, the GUI will act up. It can be seen in [this video](http://youtu.be/C1vibdZOhOs). My specs are as follows.

Windows 8.1 Update 1

Intel i5-4200u processor

Embedded Intel HD Graphics 4400

8GB DDR3 RAM, ~7.88 usable

Java version 7 Update 67 [32- and 64-bit are both installed]

Also, Minecraft is currently set to use no more than 4GB of RAM.

Has anyone else had this problem, or have a solution? I really want to play but I fear something might irreversibly mess up or something.

Comment: People are going to ask for your Java version information as well.

Comment: My guess is there is something wrong with the drivers. Which ones are you using, the ones from Intel or from Acer?

Comment: I think they're Acer, but I'm not quite clear on it.

Comment: @crayzeedude are the drivers not the standard ones you got with the pc?

Comment: I don't believe they're not standard. I haven't done anything with my installed graphics drivers since the reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a long hiatus, I finally decided to update my graphics drivers. This worked, and I can now play Minecraft like normal again.